# How do I calculate perimeter of xy points in R?

Tags: r, polygon, shapes, area

I am looking to calculate the perimeter of xy points (including all the points in sequential order), where the first and last point aren't always equal. I can't figure out why the code below for calculating perimeter isn't working.

Ideally, I would like a method which flags when the first and last xy points are different.

Thanks

```
  m
       x       y
 [1,]  606.3   95.4
 [2,]  612.4  178.7
 [3,]  610.2  222.6
 [4,]  610.2  222.8
 [5,]  625.8  249.8
 [6,]  625.8  250.1
 [7,]  633.9  268.9
 [8,]  668.7  272.2
 [9,]  693.7  222.6
[10,]  723.2  157.0
[11,]  738.6  109.9
[12,]  681.2   90.5
[13,]  606.3   95.4
[14,]  833.3  154.6
[15,]  753.7  267.5
[16,]  747.8  305.1
[17,]  773.8  354.7
[18,]  767.0  393.8
[19,]  763.0  442.0
[20,]  817.4  446.9
[21,]  817.6  446.9
[22,]  840.2  412.3
[23,]  892.1  317.7
[24,]  875.3  218.8
[25,]  833.3  154.6


library(geosphere)
perimeter(m)


**Error in perimeter(m) : could not find function "perimeter"**
```

Comment: did you install the package? You need to install it the first time you use it on your computer, after this you'll just need the `library()` call evertime you open a new R environment. You can install it with `install.packages("geosphere")`

Comment: Yes - I've installed the geosphere package

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick..

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
m <- fread("x       y
  606.3   95.4
  612.4  178.7
  610.2  222.6
  610.2  222.8
  625.8  249.8
  625.8  250.1
  633.9  268.9
  668.7  272.2
  693.7  222.6
  723.2  157.0
  738.6  109.9
  681.2   90.5
  606.3   95.4
  833.3  154.6
  753.7  267.5
  747.8  305.1
  773.8  354.7
  767.0  393.8
  763.0  442.0
  817.4  446.9
  817.6  446.9
  840.2  412.3
  892.1  317.7
  875.3  218.8
  833.3  154.6")
```

**code**

```
library( grDevices )

hull <- chull( m ) #create coordinates of convex hull
coords <- m[ c( hull, hull[1]), ]  # create a closed perimeter-polygon

#plot it
plot(m)        #plot points
lines(coords, col="red") #plot perimeter
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I should have specified in the question - is it possible to edit this so all the points in the plot are included in the perimeter (in the order in the table)?